# Staging architecture on AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails, node.js, consolidation

We are using AWS (EC2-classic) and I will migrate our servers to AWS VPC, we will use AuroraDB, too.

Staging ENV has 8servers (Linux Ubuntu 14.04), and on these servers are running RoR & node.js applications.
I was thinking to consolidate these servers into one server.

Pros

- easier maintenance
- we will be able to save money (cca $1,5k which I can theoretically spend in production ENV :) )

Cons

- can be harder to troubleshoot of issues on servers
- more apps on one server can theoretically cause more problems

I looked on usage of performance for last couple weeks and we should be OK on based of performance with new server

It is staging ENV, so we dont need high availability for this.

what is your opinion or experience?

Comment: In My opinion you can go with Containers (Docker Service). In this way you can run multiple container with different applications running with minimum resource utilization on **ONE INSTANCE**.

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on what your staging environment is suppose to achieve, but personally I'd want my staging environment to mirror the architecture of my production architecture but at a smaller scale.

If my application has a distributed architecture then I'll want to test in a realistic distributed environment to catch things like locally persisted state or unacceptably high communication overhead before my code hits production.

If your pre-production environment is only used to preview the system and check it makes some noise then it probably won't matter much either way.

Comment: thexacre, thx for your opinion, I am going to try to consolidate staging servers and if it will not work, I will come back to dedicate servers which will be mirror of production.